# ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged - Machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am getting the following error when I try to import two text files for training in Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 31, in <module>
X_train, y_train = load_mnist('mnist', kind='train')
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 27, in load_mnist
dtype=np.uint8).reshape(len(labels), 784)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

The part of code that is running is:

```
import os
import struct
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def load_mnist(path, kind='train'):
    """Load MNIST data from `path`"""
    labels_path = os.path.join(path,'%s-labels-idx1-ubyte' % kind)
    images_path = os.path.join(path, '%s-images-idx3-ubyte' % kind)

    with open('C:/Users/user/~MNISTnumLabels5000.txt', 'rb') as lbpath:
        magic, n = struct.unpack('>II', lbpath.read(8))
        labels = np.fromfile(lbpath, dtype=np.uint8)

    with open('C:/Users/user/~MNISTnumImages5000.txt', 'rb') as imgpath:
        magic, num, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", imgpath.read(16))
        images = np.fromfile(imgpath, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(len(labels), 784)

    return images, labels

X_train, y_train = load_mnist('mnist', kind='train')
print('Rows: %d, columns: %d' % (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]))
```

MNISTnumImages5000.txt file has data for 5,000 digits, each a grayscale image of size 28x28 pixels (i.e., 784 pixels each). Each row of the data file has 784 values representing the intensities of the image for one digit between 0 and 9.

MNISTnumLabels5000.txt file has one integer in each row, indicating the
correct label of the image in the corresponding row in the image data file. Thus, the first entry '7' indicates that the first row of the image data file has data for a handwritten number 7.

Comment: try 783 (zero based indexing)

Comment: can you print len(labels) and the shape of np.fromfile(imgpath...) ?

Comment: @Alexander : it still gives the error. If I remove the reshape, it is giving me :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    print('Rows: %d, columns: %d' % (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @Vasanth : Could you tell me the code to that?

Comment: print len(labels);
print np.fromfile(imgpath, dtype=np.uint8).shape

Comment: @Vasanth print len(labels) = 9992 but can't use print np.fromfl(imgpath, dtype=np.uint8)shape

Comment: Shouldn't that be 5000 since you have 5k entries?
Reshape just rearranges the elements so the array images should contain len(labels)*784 entries. If that doesn't match, you will get the 'total size...' error.

Comment: @Vasanth 5000 does not work either, and I used shape instead of reshape and that gives me a "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable" which I don't think is the correct way anyway

Comment: Reshape and shape are not the same function. First one let's you rearrange and change the shape and the shape function one returns the current shape. Can you print the current shape and tell me what it is?

Comment: @Vasanth: print (len(labels)) = 9992, print np.fromfile(imgpath, dtype=np.uint8).shape = (11292551,)

Comment: Either your files have wrong number of elements or there is some error in the way it is read. You should be getting 784*len(labels) as the shape value.